# Discord.py - Sending images without blocking other commands from running

Tags: python, discord, python-asyncio, discord.py

I need to send a picture, but while It is loading I don't want other commands being blocked from running until it finishes.
Is there a way to do this?
Maybe with asyncio or online image API's?

Thanks in advance!

Note:
This is how I currently send Images:

```
await ctx.send(file=discord.File('pics\doni (14).jpg'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to, as every command is an `async` function, meaning a coroutine. I've tested with a bot code that runs a computationally heavy expression (`3 ** 1000000` which takes 10+ seconds to run) and entered it in two separate channels at the same time. The outputs were almost exactly together (although slightly slower as the processor was loaded higher).

Comment: I have just tested it. In different channels - the commands can work simontaneously, but in the same channel they cannot. Is there a way to fix that?